# Optimizing a robot vacuum's path

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, bots

I'm trying to solve the Botclean problem on Hackerrank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/botclean

The solution I came up with will scan the board for the dirty tile with the shortest distance then navigate to it, clean it, and repeat until it's all clean.

***Code***:

```
nextD = []

def next_move(posr, posc, board):
    global nextD

    if nextD == []:
        nextD = next_d(posr,posc,board)


    if (nextD[0] == posr) and (nextD[1] == posc):
        print("CLEAN")
        board[posr][posc] = "-"
        nextD = []
        return 

    if posc < nextD[1]:
        print("RIGHT")
        return
        #posc += 1
    elif posc > nextD[1]:
        print("LEFT")
        return
        #posc -= 1 

    if posr < nextD[0]:
        print("DOWN")
        return
        #posr += 1
    elif posr > nextD[0]:
        print("UP")
        return
        #posr -= 1


#find closest d
def next_d(posr, posc, board):
    arr = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        try:
            #print("Distance to: ", i, board[i].index('d'), abs(i-posc) + abs(board[i].index('d')))
            vals = [abs(i-posr) + abs(board[i].index('d')-posc), i, board[i].index('d')]
            arr.append(vals)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    arr.sort()
    return [arr[0][1], arr[0][2]]

# Tail starts here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pos = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()]
    board = [[j for j in input().strip()] for i in range(5)]
    next_move(pos[0], pos[1], board)
```

I'm stuck at 17.60/17.82. My bot gets 16, 20, 34, 26 on the test cases. The best scores are 16, 25, 28 and 18. The discussion says to implement a greedy algorithm though I'm not entirely sure how in this context. Any suggestions for optimizing this problem? Did I go about it completely wrong?

edit: Time isn't a criteria. So scanning the board repeatedly isn't necessarily a problem.

If you want to watch it in action:
https://www.hackerrank.com/showgame/4843664

Thank you!

Comment: Some of the best scores are higher than your score and some are lower: 16-16, 20-25, 34-28 and 26-18. What does it mean?!

Comment: The algorithm you are using is greedy. At each step, you make the locally optimum choice in the hope that this will approximate the globally optimum solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking how to optimize existing code which is more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @TomDalton I honestly don't know how to reconcile those two. I got the scores from a mod post: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/botclean/forum/comments/17590.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz,Thanks! I thought so but wasn't sure.

Comment: @cpburnz I guess... I think I'm really asking for the optimal solution rather than an optimized version of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

```
nextD = []
def next_move(posr, posc, board):
    global nextD

    if nextD == []:
        nextD = next_d(posr,posc,board)

    if (nextD[0] == posr) and (nextD[1] == posc):
        print("CLEAN")
        board[posr][posc] = "-"
        nextD = []
    elif posc < nextD[1]:
        print("RIGHT")
    elif posc > nextD[1]:
        print("LEFT")
    elif posr < nextD[0]:
        print("DOWN")
    elif posr > nextD[0]:
        print("UP")


#find closest d
def next_d(posr, posc, board):
    val = len(board) * 2
    nextD = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] == 'd' and abs(i - posr) + abs(j - posc) < val:
                val = abs(i - posr) + abs(j - posc)
                nextD = [i, j]

    return nextD


# Tail starts here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pos = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()]
    board = [[j for j in input().strip()] for i in range(5)]
    next_move(pos[0], pos[1], board)
```